# Is it possible to run IHostedService instances inside a WindowsService?

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I am trying to convert a Console app into a Windows Service. The Console app is created using IWebHostBuilder. In the Startup, I register multiple IHostedService singletons. When running as a console, the app starts just fine.

However, if I follow the steps described in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.2 and I try to start the app as a Windows Service, it just freezes until you get the typical error: service timed out.

Commenting out the lines in the Startup that register the IHostedService instances does the trick, and I can get the service running.

Are there any technical limitations that prevent us from using IWebHostBuilder + IHostedService + Windows Service?

Comment: Is there any logic in the hosted service that blocks startup? This would case the program not to report its state to the windows service system thus causing the timeout.

Comment: Please try to create a [minimal, complete and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) when asking such questions since otherwise the question would risk being closed.

Comment: @MartinUllrich yes, the hosted service gets blocked when waiting for items to be queued in a BlockingCollection. Basically, I have the main request thread adding items into the blocking collection, and the hosted service will react on that action. But as a side effect, now I am experiencing this issue.